# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax for inner query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to show roll, name and the count of students older than the current student for each row. But I am getting this error

```
    SELECT sd1.Roll, sd1.Name, COUNT(
        SELECT Roll
        FROM student_details  sd2
        WHERE sd2.Age > sd1.Age
        )

    FROM student_details  sd1 LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
    check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version 
    for the right syntax to use near 
    'SELECT Roll
            FROM student_details  sd2
            WHERE sd2.Age > sd1.Age
    ' at line 2
```

in my query.

```
SELECT sd1.Roll, sd1.Name, COUNT(
    SELECT Roll
    FROM student_details  sd2
    WHERE sd2.Age > sd1.Age
    )

FROM student_details  sd1;
```

my database table "student_details" is something like

[image: student_details]

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: Where in the docs (or elsewhere) did you find that `COUNT()` can be used with a sub-query as a parameter.

Comment: thanks PM 77-1 for your concern. I didn't find it in any docs, I just guessed it and tried to use, my bad. Now I know what was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a correlated select subquery inside `count` aggregate function like that.

It seems like what you want to do is for each student obtain a count of how many students are there that are older from each student. Use `LEFT JOIN` for this, in case there are no older students, and `count(sd2.Roll)` to only count younger ones (pulled from `sd2`).

```
SELECT sd1.Roll, sd1.Name, count(sd2.Roll)
FROM student_details sd1
LEFT JOIN student_details sd2 on
  sd2.Age > sd1.Age
GROUP BY sd1.Roll, sd1.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a query inside a `count` function like that. But you could use a correlated subquery;

```
SELECT sd1.Roll, sd1.Name, (SELECT COUNT(*)
                            FROM   student_details  sd2
                            WHERE  sd2.Age > sd1.Age)
FROM   student_details sd1
LIMIT  0, 25
```